# Can I create an external http link to a section of a Word document shared on OneDrive?

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, onedrive, hyperlink, microsoft-word-365

I know how to share a URL to a Word document that's shared via OneDrive. I also know how to create a bookmark to link to a section of the document from another location within that document.

I want to combine the two: just like I can add "#" to a URL of a webpage to be able to jump to a section, can I modify the URL to the Word document to jump directly to a section of that document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can only be done in the web version of Word. To accomplish this, you can add a heading and then right click on that heading and select "Copy Link to Heading" (see image below).

[image]

---

There is an open feedback request with Microsoft to add this to the Windows App: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/1d63b1b1-9d2c-ee11-a81c-6045bdbbbc93

Comment: Thanks! crazy that this is not available in the desktop app!

Comment: Top tip - thanks! And yes, annoying it's not in the desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for :

1. Select the text or object that you want to display as the hyperlink
2. Right-click and select *Link > Insert link*
3. Click "Existing File or Web Page" on the left
4. Select the folder and the target document inside it
5. Click Bookmark... and select the bookmark from the target document
6. Click OK.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for something different. I want to send the link to a shared document to someone else. I can send them the URL and when they open it they will see the beginning of the document. But it's a long document so I want them to jump directly to the section that I want to bookmark. So something like <URL_TO_DOC>#<SECTION> instead of simply <URL_TO_DOC>

Comment: Word does not have such a feature. The most I can think of is to put in the document a bookmark named, for example, "See This", or some other agreed-upon name.